# LINQ query on datatable showing empty column

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I am trying to display values of three columns, but I am able to get values of only two columns `ID` and `TOTAL`. It returns an empty column for `Medical_Store`.

Below is my code

```
var newDt = (from p in dt_1.AsEnumerable()
             group p by p["invoice_id"]
             into r
             select new
             {
                 ID = r.Key,
                 Total = r.Sum((s) => decimal.Parse(s["total_price"].ToString())),
                 MEDICAL_STORE = r.Select((s) => (s["medical_store_name"].ToString()))
             })
            .ToList();
dataGrid2.ItemsSource = newDt;
```

Comment: Does `dt_1` contains `medical_store_name` this column?

Comment: What's medical store supposed to contain? The list of all medical stores in the group?

Comment: It contains medical store name

Comment: @KeyurRamoliya yes dt_1 contains medical_store_name

Comment: Thanks @mjwills you solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your query is not populating `MEDICAL_STORE` with a **single** medical store, but a collection / enumerable of them.

I suspect instead of:

```
MEDICAL_STORE = r.Select((s) => (s["medical_store_name"].ToString()))
```

that you wish to use:

```
MEDICAL_STORE = r.Max((s) => (s["medical_store_name"].ToString()))
```

to get a **single** value instead.